# Why is 4.+(2) deprecated in scala

Tags: scala, methods, int, operator-keyword, deprecated

Typing the following into the scala console gets me what i expect:

```
scala> println(4+2)
6
```

However the following gives me a `Double` as output instead of `Int`:

```
scala> println(4.+(2))
6.0
```

It warns me that this syntax is deprecated and from scala 2.11 a dot after a number will only be considered part/method of the number if it is immediatly followed by another digit.
So it seems that `num1 + num2` is not shorthand for `num1.+(num2)` but rather a special kind of operator.

Why did they decide to make a special operator instead of only just using the `+ method` of the `Int` class? Also why did they choose to make the `+ method` accepting and returning `Double` and the `+ operator` not? Java compatibility?

Comment: `4.` looks like `4.0`. I don’t know Scala, but I bet `(4).+(2)` would work. (`4..+2`?) The deprecation notice is also warning you that the behaviour you expect *will* work in the future =)

Comment: Ha, `4..+(2)` is indeed ok for 2.10 but an error for 2.11.  The future is now!  Also, the printlns are undesirable.  The p in repl is for print.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `1.` is equivalent to `1.0` in Scala, C or Java. Thus for the compiler `4.+(2)` is equivalent to `(4.)+(2)` which is equal to `6.0`...

To supress this ambiguity, this syntax will be discontinued. However, you can still use `(4).+(2)`.

Comment: To clarify, the discontinued syntax is taking `4.` as `4.0`; it now takes `4.+(2)` the way you'd expect. So the same syntax means something different.